# Site logo messed up on Chrome (Android) and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I’ve just moved my website to Genesis 2.0 and I am using the bone stock genesis. Its running all fine on desktop (Chrome, FireFox). But on Android (tested on Galaxy S4 and Galaxy Nexus) and Chrome, the logo gets all messed up. This is how it looks:

[image: Current status]

Where as this is how it should look:

[image: Desired result]

However, it works on fine with FireFox on Android.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update: Just tested on iPhone 5 and Safari. Same issue.

Comment: Provide some HTML & CSS code for the logo perhaps?

Comment: Ah - i see that issue every day, and i also happen to be able to be omniscient, no, where is your code?

Comment: There isnt really any HTML since the logo is added by a hook in Genesis. However, you can see the CSS here: http://www.chiploco.com/wp-content/themes/chiploco-v3/style.css?ver=2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way to test this, but this code here looks suspect:

```
.header-image .site-header .wrap {
    background: url(images/logo@2x.png) no-repeat left;
    background-size: 320px 164px;
}
```

That background-size rule could create the stretching effect you see.